# Is it possible to consume a web service deployed in glassfish by an application on client side using apache tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jpa, glassfish

this may be two questions in one, so...Sorry, please correct me if I'm wrong.

I have to deploy a web service developed with JPA, JSP and Glassfish 3.1.2, in a machine which only has apache Tomcat 7 as server installed on Windows 7.

I don't really know how apache can connect to the database externally, or if that is really possible if you don't use TomEE.

I know in Glassfish you can have a connection pool and a jdbc resource, and if you're using JPA, that's how the connection to database works(kindof), so you can deploy the .war file. But, if you only have a Tomcat and the app is using JPA, so it does not connect itself to the database(It does not have a class with a connection credentials), How can I achieve this?

Or, Can I deploy the .war of the web service on Glassfish and then be consumed by an application that only works with apache Tomcat on client side? Am I mixing concepts which should not be mixed?

Any enlightenment is highly appreciated.

Comment: You should have no problem connecting to a DB with Tomcat, if you provided more detail perhaps someone on this forum could help. What did you try? What were the symptoms of your failure. Deployment details, logs, database type, url, root user, on and on . . .

Comment: Oka, I've edited the question a bit.  I want to know if deploying a web service in a server(Glassfish), this can be consumed from an application which uses another different server, like Apache Tomcat, or if its better to have both on the same environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Tomcat with JPA, you can even use it in a standalone java application. Define a persistence unit name in persistence.xml, make sure the transaction type is RESOURCE_LOCAL (you can't use JTA in Tomcat, make sure to check this), and get a reference to the EM using the following

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistenceUnitName");
em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Finally, add the jpa provider jars to Tomcat, there are examples for that (I've never done it, but I'm sure some Tomcat expert could lend a hand)

The other option could also work, that is consume your webservice using a client deployed on another server

Good luck!

Comment: True. There are jars allowing this kind of connections with persistence, or instead using TomEE, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it without a lot of config from server side.

Answer (score 0):

If your application uses advanced Java EE functionality (JTA, CDI), it won't work on Tomcat. If it uses JSTL, you will have to add a JSTL library to the tomcat installation. Read the docs, it should be stated somewhere, but I would **not** simply deploy the war to a tomcat.

If you just want to develop a *relay* webapp that consumes a webservice and displays the results, it **will** run on tomcat independantly of where the webservice runs.

Comment: Yes, I've read some docs and it is stated there are another ways to use advanced Java EE functionality with the help of some third-party libraries, which I didn't wanted to do.